# How to make a button in htmlinfowindows call a function in .ts passing parameter?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic3

I'm using the googlemaps native plugin for ionic and present a htmlinfowindows whenever a pin is touched. This part is running smoothly.

I am trying to put buttons in htmlinfowindows, each calling a function in my ts passing an id, but I am not able to click on the buttons call the functions. I've tried several forms of calls, as follows:

I have this in my .ts:

```
   this.map.addMarker({
       'html': content,  // here I feed the HTML with the attempts below
        icon: {       // it is the content that appears in the htmlinfowindow window
          'url': icone
        },
        position: {
           lat: lat,
           lng: lng
        }
   }).then(marker => {
       marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
       .subscribe(() => {
            if (this.auxi){
               this.auxi = null;
            }
            var htmlInfo = new HtmlInfoWindow();
            htmlInfo.setContent(marker.get('html'));
            htmlInfo.open(marker);
            this.auxi = htmlInfo;
       });
  });

  test(param){
    console.log(param);
  }
```

My attempts in var content:

```
   click is not detected
   var content = '<div><button type="buttton" (click)="test(\'idtest\');">update price</button></div>';

   Uncaught TypeError: this.test is not a function
   var content = '<div><button type="buttton" onclick="this.test(\'idteste\');">update price</button></div>';

   Uncaught TypeError: test is not a function
   var content = '<div><button type="buttton" onclick="test(\'idtest\');">update price</button></div>';
```

So I tried to fire a click on an invisible button in my .html where the (click) call my function:

in .html

```
  <button ion-button [hidden]='true'  (click)='test(event)' id="bot"></button>
```

in .ts

```
   var content = '<div><button type="buttton" onclick="document.getElementById(\'bot\').click({\'param\': \'idtest\'}, this.test);">update price</button></div>';
```

In the above form, the click event of the invisible button is triggered, but I do not know how to make it forward to the function test the parameter coming from htmlinfowindow.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem, thanks

Comment: No, I give up and just enable the touch of the window

Comment: @George After many tests and study I was able to solve. I'll post the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post my solution here too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who encountered the same problem, the solution to create the buttons with DOM and addEventListener, as follows:

```
for(var estab of this.arrayEstabs){
      var placeId = estab.PlaceId;
      var lat = estab.Lat;
      var lng = estab.Lng;
      var nome = estab.Nome;
      var html = nome+'<br>Preço <b>R$ '+this.format(estab.Preco)+'</b><br>';

      var btNavega = document.createElement("Button");
      var t = document.createTextNode("Navegar até aqui"); 
      btNavega.appendChild(t)
      btNavega.addEventListener("click", (event) => { this.showToast("test1") } );
      btNavega.setAttribute("class", "btNavega");

      var btPreco = document.createElement("Button");
      var p = document.createTextNode("Atualizar preço"); 
      btPreco.appendChild(p)
      btPreco.addEventListener("click", (event) => { this.showToast("teste2") } );
      btPreco.setAttribute("class", "btPreco");

      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = html;
      div.appendChild(btNavega);
      div.appendChild(btPreco);
      div.setAttribute("class", "infoWindow");
          this.map.addMarker({
              'html': div,
              icon: {
                'url': icone
              },
              animation: 'DROP',
              position: {
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng
              }
            })
          .then(marker => {
              marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
                .subscribe(() => {
                  if (this.auxi){
                    this.auxi = null;
                  }
                  var htmlInfo = new HtmlInfoWindow();
                  htmlInfo.setContent(marker.get('html'));
                  htmlInfo.open(marker);
                  this.auxi = htmlInfo;
                });
          });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.